# How to convert tensor of numpy (.npy) to tensor of image

Tags: python, image, numpy, tensor

I have tensor of video frames as .npy and I want to convert the numpy tensor to image tensor. I used:

```
tensor = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
```

but it is return this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

Comment: Show the full error message